# RadDropDownTree Get Selected Value when click the Hierachy item

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Hey everyone i am using raddropdowntree,I want to get the value of raddropdowntree when user click hierarchy item. this is my

aspx code

```
<telerik:RadDropDownTree ID="RadDropDownTree1" runat="server" Width="400px" EnableFiltering="true"
            DataFieldID="COAId" DataFieldParentID="ParentCOAId" DataValueField="COAId" DataTextField="AccountDesc"
            Skin="Silk" FilterSettings-Highlight="Matches"
            OnEntryAdded="RadAutoCompleteBox1_EntryAdded" ExpandNodeOnSingleClick="true" AutoPostBack="true">
            <DropDownSettings Height="420px" OpenDropDownOnLoad="true"/>
            <ButtonSettings ShowClear="true" />
            <FilterSettings Highlight="Matches" Filter="Contains" EmptyMessage="Type   here to find a contact" />

        </telerik:RadDropDownTree>
```

this codeBehind

```
public void RadAutoCompleteBox1_EntryAdded(object sender, DropDownTreeNodeDataBoundEventArguments e)
    {
        string ID = e.Entry.Value ;
    }
```

this code works but problem is that when i select item from hierarchy. after select the item when i am click the out side of the raddropdowntree boundary so this event fire.. 
other it is not fire. what is the issue i want to call this event item selection.

Answer (score 1):

Use the client-side event OnClientEntryAdding to access this property.

ie

```
<telerik:RadDropDownTree ID="rddTree" runat="server"
  OnClientEntryAdding="OnClientEntryAdding"
  DefaultMessage="Browse Systems..."
  Skin="Default" EnableFiltering="true"
  FilterSettings-Highlight="Matches" Font-Names="Segoe UI"
  FilterSettings-EmptyMessage="Search..."
  CheckBoxes="None">
  <DropDownSettings Height="150px" AutoWidth="Enabled" 
  CloseDropDownOnSelection="true" />
</telerik:RadDropDownTree>
```

...   with the following javascript embedded

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function OnClientEntryAdding(sender, eventArgs) {

  //debugger;
  var Value = eventArgs.get_entry().get_value();
  //do something with it      
  }
</script>
```